# Тормозит сервер, как определить и устранить причину?

Tags: linux, debian

Сегодня в 11:30 на сервере появились тормоза, скрипты стали работать в 5-10 раз медленнее (никаких кардинальных изменений не вносилось). Временами отпускает, все возвращается на короткое время в норму, потом снова все начинает тормозить.

По статистике в Munin есть подозрение, что это из-за сетевой активности, но точно не могу сказать, нужна помощь знающего человека.

Какие нужны скриншоты и данные, чтобы понять в чем дело?

Данные с atop:

[image: данные с atop]
Данные с htop:
[image: htop]
Данные netstat из Munin (спецэффекты начались с 11:30)
[image: munin]
Данные с htop, память:
[image: htop]
А это при вырубленном апаче
[image: htop]

Comment: там два типа процессов, которые все выжирают. По хорошему, нужно смотреть в их логи. Если не помогает - профайлить - `timeout 20 strace -c -p <pid>` (подставить пид нужно процесса). Результат будет через 20 секунд и будет интереснее.

Comment: да, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Установите atop, там наглядно будет видно. А вообще есть замечательная, наглядная схема.

[image: Linux Performance Observability Tools]

Comment: добавил скриншот по данным в atop. можно по чему что-то сказать?

Comment: апач пробовали дебажить? Читать логи, слушать трафик `tcpdump` до него, смотреть повисшие запросы в mysqld от апача? Как крайняя мера - вырубить его и проверить, упадёт ли аверага (А она упадёт наверняка)

Comment: логи смотрел, но еще не слушал трафик. сейчас буду изучать

Comment: отрубил апач, при заходе через ssh тормоза все равно сохранились, консоль заметно притормаживает

Comment: а при вырубленном апаче что в htop/atop ?

Comment: прикрепил картинку

Comment: эмм, average нормальный, не критичный, не должно ничего тупить. Единственное что munin пыжится что-то с mysql сделать, посмотрите в сторону mysql, может там запросы какие-то долго выполняются, включите запись slow_log, посмотрите текущие процессы системной схемы.

Comment: сейчас попробую вообще отрубить мунина, посмотрим как себя поведет система

Comment: все равно тормоза. а не может это быть из-за сетевой активности?

Comment: Судя по atop она ничтожна. Снимите дамп трафика, посмотрите. Вполне возможно, какой-то паразит ддосит пакетами сервер, например, генерирует 100500 udp пакетов отрывая сокеты.

Comment: да, у меня тоже такие подозрения. сейчас займусь дампом.

Comment: снял небольшой дамп трафика, можно по нему что-то сказать? https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_FYFmwvW60qMkdjSWFYTVR1YkU

Comment: там все время фигурирует строчка cisco broadcast ARP и 60 who was XX.XX.XX.XXX (причем IP-адреса самые разные)

Comment: Обычные arp-запросы, ничего криминального. Да и пакетрейт там у Вас 20 пакетов в секунду - эта активность ниже чем вообще никакая, либо может Вы не правильно дамп сняли: `tcpdump -nni any -s0 -w /path/to/file.pcapng`

Comment: вот правильный дамп https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_FYFmwvW60qRzdUVWRoNDM4QTA

Comment: Всё то же самое - сетевая активность вообще никакая... ну можно пойти методом от противного. Как я понял, это у Вас какая-то VDS от ru-center с каким-то не очень продуктивным сайтом, раз он пустую страницу возвращает и представляется nginx'ом, хотя должен апачем... Предлагаю вырубить вообще все активные процессы кроме sshd и постепенно включать их наблюдая за load average в htop и метриками в atop. Не исключено, но маловероятно, что это проблема хостера.

Comment: В логах nginx\apache нет большого количества записей типа "YandexBot" или "Googlebot" может происходит индексация сайта?

Comment: нет, в логах все нормально. тоже склоняюсь к мысли, что проблемы у хостера, т.к. пару раз тормоза отпускало и все начинало работать четко.